# Segue without the tab bar

Tags: ios, swift

I have a app that has a tab bar at the bottom.

I am trying to segue to a new view controller via  a button that has the code:

```
@IBAction func moveOver(sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("to-image-select", sender: sender)
}
```

This works and it segues to the new view, but the tab bar is still at the bottom. How do I make the tab bar not at the bottom? Is there some way of doing a segue that doesnt carry with it the tab bar?

**EDIT 1**

I do not want the tab bar, I would prefer to have a fully clean UI for this  new view. I will have a back button that will take the user back to the previous page in the corner. I am looking into what modally segues are right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will you need your tab bar further in your navigation ?

- If **yes**, you might want to play with the hidden bool property to display it or not.
- If **no**, you could set your segue as presentModally instead of a regular push.

Hope this helps, don't hesitate to provide more information about what your are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use tabbar, you can use navigation controller, or present on top. I advise you to try a tutorial about storyboard before jumping in:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1

Good luck (: